# Fields added with Jquery in Rails 3 are not visible in controller using params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3 and Jquery to dynamically add field in a form_tag using a button "Add packages". I'm using the following code in Jquery:

```
  var counter = 1;
  $('#but').click(function()
  {
        var s = '<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form2")) %>';
        var p = $(s);
        $('#packagename', p).attr("name","packagename" + counter);
        $('#type',p).attr("name","type" + counter);
        $('#price', p).attr("name", "price" + counter);
        $('#pricetype', p).attr("name", "pricetype" + counter);
        $('#currency', p).attr("name", "currency" + counter);
        $('.fac', p).each(function(){
          $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + counter);
        });
        $('.pack').append(p);
        counter ++;
  }
```

in order to rename the "name" attribute so i can pass the values of the fields to the controller using params. This is my partial "form2"

```
<div class="span-16" style="padding-bottom:10px;" id="package">
  <%= label_tag "PACKAGE: " %> <br /> <br/>
 <%= label_tag "Name*:" %> <br />
 <%= text_field_tag :packagename %>
<br />
<%=label_tag "Type:*"%> <br />
 <% ["Private office", "Private room", "Shared desk"].each do |type| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag  "type", type, false, :class => 'option_types', :id => 'type' %>
  <%= label_tag type, type %>
<% end %>
 <%= render 'price' %>
<%= label_tag "Available facilities and amenities:" %><br />
  <% ["Printer", "Wi-Fi"].each do |fac| %>
    <%= check_box_tag  fac, fac, false, :class => 'fac' %>
    <%= label_tag fac, fac %>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

However, the parameters for the fields added with jquery are not showing in the controller or on the server's section for params.
The html source can be found here : http://pastebin.com/AszhDL8Y
Any ideas?

Comment: The "id" values of all elements on the page, including those dynamically added, must be unique.  If your click handler runs twice, that rule will be violated and the "#whatever" selectors won't work properly.

Comment: I tried $('#whatever) and if more than one element has that id it returns an array of the objects

Comment: I added different ids to each item, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm well I'm pretty sure the behavior is browser-dependent.  Have you tried using a plugin like [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for Firefox to track what's actually in the HTTP requests from the browser?  If your code is successfully adding the elements and the names (should be able to check with Firebug), then there's no reason form them to be missing (assuming they're added **inside** the `<form>` block!!).